# Hibernate Envers disable RevisionListener

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I'm using a "custom" envers RevisionListener to audit the access-token (autowired into listener, request scoped bean) at every revision.

Problem: in the setup/teardown of my integration tests I create/delete objects (that create a new revision and therefore trigger the listener) but at this point no request-scoped bean is available.

Idea: disable the RevisionListener in the test context?

Any solution for this, or other solutions are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect in an integration test scenario you would either

1. Build the request-scope bean (Spring should have a way to do this)
2. Use Mockito to build such a Mock bean you then inject into Spring DI.

There really is no reason to provide a toggle to "disable" the revision listener as the problem can be resolved by properly setting up your test environment to truly support a real integration test scenario.